# How do I get Navigation bar on only the last screen in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

If I've got 6 screens total and I'm wanting to add a navigation controller between my last two scenes so my final screen has a nav bar/ navigation through a navigation controller is there an easy way to do that?

I've tried embedding a nav controller into my first scene and switching my segues to "show" and setting the navigationbar.isHidden to true in appear and then on my last screen trying to set it to false in viewdidappear and then to true again in viewdiddissapear.

First of all it didn't work, (I just need to tinker with it probably), but secondly it seems like a lot of "work" just to get navigation between two screens.

Do you have to have navigation throughout your entire project to get navigation between two specific screens? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a storyboard, you should be able to select the second-last screen and use the Editor->Embed in->Navigation controller menu item.

Comment: I feel like I had tried that a hundred times last night, and today that worked like a charm.

Thank you! That's a lot simpler than having navigation throughout the entire project and hiding the bar.

Comment: I do have one question actually. So I'm passing variables between my screens in prepare for segue, and when embedding in the navigation controller I'm getting an error that the destinationVC is no longer the one I'm assigning and now it's the Nav Controller which makes sense.  

Is there a smooth way to maintain the variable passing with this nav controller now in play?

Alternatively is there any way to just force a navigation bar onto a view without navigation control at all? I'm using JSQMessages and just need a way out of the screen.

Comment: I don't have a quick solution.  I try to avoid passing data between controllers so that issues like that don't happen.  If you use MVC structure, each controller just asks the Model for the information it needs to display instead of having built-in dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In the `viewController` that you want to hide the `navBar` add the following in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.navigationController!.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```